# Special Characters in Template Group Name (Chinese Characters)

Tags: templates, multi-language, language, template-manager

We have a translated page in Chinese just so we can give the Chinese users a quick understanding in there language what the website is about. We want to display it here: domain.com/中文

Where 中文 = chinese so that part of the URL is also in there language.

Easiest way I'd of thought would be to make a Template group and give it the name 中文 and then create and index page and boom - its done.

Expression Engine however only seems to accept unicode characters or something because characters with accents and Chinese, Japanese Korean etc characters are not allowed. Anyone know of a work around or a way for Chinese characters to be accepted?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use template groups like that, it can't handle double byte characters, only alphanumeric.

Ideally you need to use a multi-language add-on like [Publisher](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/publisher) or [Transcribe](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/transcribe) which allow for translated URLs.

Just tried it with [Construct](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/construct) and it crashes it, so that's not an option :(

On a simpler solution, I've just tried it with Template Routes (built into EE2 and EE3 versions), which does allow you to set up specific routes from your "/中文" page to a specific template - therefore you can mask the template name. But this may get complex if you have lots of pages you want to implement this with. The issue is also compounded in Entries can only have alphanumeric for the url_title - so how will you match dynamic content?